# How to disable warning in js2-mode: function does not always return a value?

Tags: major-mode, javascript, js2-mode

Is it possible to disable warning for functions that not always return value in js2-mode?

Comment: look at `js2-ingored-warnings` variable

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan describe variable can't find it and there is no such varaible in [the source](https://github.com/mooz/js2-mode/blob/master/js2-mode.el)

Comment: Are you sure? Maybe emacs had not loaded `js2-mode`. Open a `.js` file and search for a variable after opening that file

Comment: The variable is called `js2-ignored-warnings`.

Comment: maybe something with the version, I'm using GNU Emacs 24.5.1 but I've get js2-mode from elpa. I've call `customize-group` and there is no such variable.

Comment: Have you tried changing `js2-strict-inconsistent-return-warning` ?

Also most people disable js2-mode warnings and use `flycheck` with some linter.

Comment: @caisah that solved the issue, you can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable responsible for this is `js2-strict-inconsistent-return-warning`. Just set it to `nil`.